# Prolog backtracking: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

Tags: prolog, backtracking, instantiation-error

I have the following problem:

Generate all sub-strings of a length 2*n+1, formed from values of 0, 1 or -1, so a1 = ..., a2n+1 = 0 and |a(i+1) - ai| = 1 or 2, for every 1 <= i <= 2n.
This is what I found here on stack overflow but the solution used a clpfd library and I am not allowed to use any kind of library whatsoever:

```
change(0).
change(1).
change(-1).

%gets the last element from a list
lastE([X],X).
lastE([_|L],X) :-
    last(L,X).

%checks if |N-M|=1 or 2
calc(N,M) :-
    (  1 is abs(N-M)
    ;  2 is abs(N-M),
       ! 
    ).

%generates all lists of length N with values -1,0,1
generate([],0) :-
!.
generate([H|T],N):-
    change(H),
    N1 is N-1,
    generate(T,N1).

%validates a list to be correct (last element=0, |a(i+1) - ai| = 1 or 2)
valid(L) :-
   valid(L,_,3).

valid([E],_,_) :-
    lastE([E],0).
valid([H|[H1|T]],_,3) :-
    valid([H1|T],H,H1).
valid([_|[H1|T]],N,M) :-
    calc(N,M),
    valid([H1|T],M,H1).
```

<strike>All of the above code works correctly (I tested it). But with the following code for genAll, I get the Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated error.</strike>

```
genAll(N) :-
    N1 is 2*N,
    N2 is N1+1,
    generate(L1,N2),
    valid(L1),
    write('['),
printl(L1).

printl([]) :-
    write(']').
printl([0|T]) :-
    write('0 '),
    printl(T).
printl([1|T]) :-
    write('1 '),
   printl(T).
printl([-1|T]) :-
    write('-1 '),
printl(T).
```

I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: What query did you make? Did you try doing a `trace` to see where it fails? By the way, CLPFD is integral to GNU Prolog (it's not considered an external library) and is a fundamental part of Prolog. Are you sure you can't use it?

Comment: I use SWI-Prolog and I'm not even allowed to use basic already made functions like "member", I have to make my own versions.

I get this when I try to run genAll(2):
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated.


I believe something is wrong with the "valid" predicate but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: You need to do a `trace`. I did a `trace` with the query `genAll(3)` and it eventually failed with the statement, `1 is abs(_698-3)` which will fail with an instantiation error. This issue is avoided with CLPFD and `#=`. The code you copied from stack overflow was designed to use CLPFD.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use CLPFD. I did a `trace` with the query `genAll(2)` and it also failed with `1 is abs(_G2700-3)`

Comment: The trace will show you how it got there. That's what `trace` does. You'll need to look through that logic and see what's happening. If needed try a simpler case, like `genAll(1)` if that's a valid case.

Comment: When you say, *All of the above code works correctly (I tested it)* you left out some tests perhaps. `valid([0,0,0])` fails with the error (the trace I mentioned will show this), so the code doesn't work correctly.

Comment: `genAll(1)` is a valid case but it fails just as well. The problem is that the `valid` predicate tries to pass an unknown value to the `calc` witch fails as a result. How can I change `valid ` so it will work correctly?

Comment: Yes, the `valid` predicate is in fact not working correctly, I edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: I know `genAll(1)` fails, it just does so in fewer steps so may be easier to trace. And rather than "fix" `valid`, you could, for example, try to fix `calc` by checking if the argument is instantiated. If it isn't, calculate separately the other direction. `calc` will become more elaborate in that case. You need to compensate for the fact that you removed CLPFD.

Comment: I changed the `calc` predicate to this :

    `calc(N,M) :-
    integer(N),
    integer(M),

    (  1 is abs(N-M)
    ;  2 is abs(N-M),
       !
    ).`

But it only generates one of the many possible combinations.

Comment: A cut will prevent any backtracking so could prune out solutions. In addition, the original `calc` predicate, since it used CLPFD, may have fully intended to obtain a solution to `1 #= abs(N-M)` if one of `N` or `M` is not instantiated, whereas your rewrite won't do so. You would need an alternative in your `calc` predicate for the case where either `integer(N)` (or `integer(M)`) fails which would determine the value of `N` (or `M`) which makes the expression true.